# Pushing a new element onto and array changes another element

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script

Here's a function that manipulates arrays that I'm having trouble with:

```
function playWithArrays2()
{

    var OneDimArray = [];
    var TwoDimArray = [];
    OneDimArray.push('Row 0,Value 0');
    OneDimArray.push('Row 0,Value 1');
    OneDimArray.push('Row 0,Value 2');
    TwoDimArray.push(OneDimArray);

    OneDimArray = [];
    OneDimArray.push('Row 1,Value 0');
    OneDimArray.push('Row 1,Value 1');
    OneDimArray.push('Row 1,Value 2');
    TwoDimArray.push(OneDimArray); 

    var HoldArray = TwoDimArray[0];
    HoldArray[0] = "New Value";

    TwoDimArray.push(HoldArray);

    Logger.log(TwoDimArray);

}
```

I'm attempting to copy a row of a 2 dimensional array to a single row array, modify a column in the single row array, and then push it onto the 2 dimensional array.  Here's the output from the log:

> [17-12-25 21:55:16:660 EST] [[New Value, Row 0,Value 1, Row 0,Value 2], [Row 1,Value 0, Row 1,Value 1, Row 1,Value 2], [New Value, Row 0,Value 1, Row 0,Value 2]]

As you can see the push works fine: A 3rd, altered row is created.  The problem is that the first row is also altered.  That's the row that was assigned to the 1 dimensional array.

I don't want to alter that 1st row.  That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Array in javascript are also object and variables holds reference to an object, not the object itself. In your case `var HoldArray = TwoDimArray[0];`, `HoldArray` have the reference to 0 row of `TwoDimArray`, you are modifying the values inside this reference, that's why it is affecting the values at the both of the places as both values have the same reference.

You can create a copy of an array using [`array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var HoldArray = TwoDimArray[0].slice(0);
```

```js
var OneDimArray = [];
var TwoDimArray = [];
OneDimArray.push('Row 0,Value 0');
OneDimArray.push('Row 0,Value 1');
OneDimArray.push('Row 0,Value 2');
TwoDimArray.push(OneDimArray);

OneDimArray = [];
OneDimArray.push('Row 1,Value 0');
OneDimArray.push('Row 1,Value 1');
OneDimArray.push('Row 1,Value 2');
TwoDimArray.push(OneDimArray); 

var HoldArray = TwoDimArray[0].slice(0);
HoldArray[0] = "New Value";

TwoDimArray.push(HoldArray);
console.log(TwoDimArray);
```

Comment: Thanks Hassah!  slice(0) worked like a champ.  I knew that my HoldArray was a pointer to the row of the 2 dimensional array but didn't know how to create an unlinked copy.  I really appreciate your help.